# Proof involving derivative product rule for transpose and gradient

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

> Let $f,g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be differentiable
> functions and let $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
> $h(t) = f(t) \cdot g(t)$.
>
> Prove that $\frac{dh}{dt}(a) = (Df(a))^T \cdot g(a) + f(a) \cdot (Dg(a))^T$,
>
> where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $M^T$ represents the transpose of a
> matrix $M$ (we are considering, for example, the row matrix
> $(Df(a))^T$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I know that this has something to do with gradient vectors and product rule, but I actually have no ideia of how to prove this. Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track the vector components.

Let $f_i, g_i$ be the vector components of the function values. Note that $(Df)_i=\frac{d}{dt}f_i$.

$$
\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\sum_i f_i(t) g_i(t)=\sum_i f_i(t)\frac{d}{dt}g_i(t)+g_i(t)\frac{d}{dt}f_i(t)
$$

which leads to the product rule formula you stated by definition.

The use of transpose in the original statement is superfluous. Transpose only matters if you phrase $h$ as the matrix-vector multiplication of $f^Tg$, where you can see the application of (the true $\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$) product rule simply retains the transpose on $f$; except that is not what your question asks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a question: isn't $Dfi$ equals to the column vector?

Comment: @Hitagi: $Df$ is a n-D column vector. What is your question again?

Comment: I see, thank you! But I'm still a bit confused because I didn't understand what you said about the use of transpose. I solved this exercise as you did in your answer, but I got $Dfi(a)gi(a)+fi(a)Dgi(a)$. Would that be the same as what was originally stated?

Comment: @Hitagi: Basically, ignore the transpose part. The question should not have stated it. And yes, it would mean the same. But your notation is also a bit off. If you mean vector component of a function, with $Df$ being a single function, it's better to put brackets over before writing subscript, ie. $(Df)_i$, in order to disambiguate away from $D(f_i)$. $(Df)\cdot g$ means exactly the same as $(Df)^T \cdot g$ with $\cdot$ standing for dot-product. (Except the latter is not good. Let's just save that for the future if you dont immediately spot why.)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you! And I apologize for my weird notation, I had no ideia that this could generate an ambiguous interpretation. I guess I understand now what you meant, but I still can't see why is $(Df)\cdot g$ the same as $(Df)^T \cdot g$. Is it possible to prove this somehow?

Comment: @Hitagi: The mean the same by definition. The transpose sign is a misnomer.

Comment: I see. I didn't know that. Thank you very much for your help! And sorry for bothering you with my dumb questions lol.

Comment: @Hitagi: Asking questions in order to learn is never dumb :) (Though I am not going to say questions can never be dumb. Cuz, in life, they can be.)